# BlackBerry:How to lock the screen orientation for Storm?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

I want to lock the orientation programmatically for my application screens to be displayed only in Portrait mode. I use Storm BB device. How to do lock it via my code?

Can someone hint me how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your application to only allow specific orientations by passing in specific direction parameters when invoking [UiEngineInstance.setAcceptableDirections(int)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiEngineInstance.html#setAcceptableDirections(int)).

Comment: I resolved it. Now i'm able to lock the application screen into portrait mode always. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I try to lock the orientation to portrait, but open the application while the device is in landscape, the app will open in landscape and lock to portrait(as it was set) only after the user rotates the device. Here's what the documentation says: "The screen direction only changes once the device is rotated to a direction supported by the provided direction parameter."

Comment: Yes, this is very annoying.  Some apps display a screen that says "this orientation is not supported" but that's not an ideal solution.